# Отправить JSON на сервер с одновременным переходом на другую страницу

Tags: php, json

Ситуация такая. Я хочу отправить JS-объект в виде JSON на php-страницу с переходом на нее. Эта новая страница генерируется как-раз из переданных данных.

Приведу пример. Есть JS-объект

```
{
   {id: 1; name: 'Вася'},
   {id: 2; name: 'Маша'}
}
```

Его отправляю в обработчик, строю таблицу из этих объектов и хочу перейти на страницу с этой таблицей.

Я могу отправить ajax-запросом объект на эту страницу, обработать, но как сделать переход на эту страницу с уже обработанными данными?

Попытался кнопку отправки обернуть в форму. Эффект нужный, данные отправляются, переход осуществяется, но как и в предыдущем случае данных на странице в таком случае нет

Comment: Пишите в суксесс `location.href=URL`. Радуетесь

Comment: в смысле в xhr.onreadystatechange при ответе 200? Но в таком случае как я получу доступ к уже созданной таблице?

Comment: @Сергей а на какой стороне ты строишь таблицу? Если на сервере то, тебе без разницы, при переходе на страницу данные с сервера придут с уже готовой таблицей

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев на сервере. Вопрос в том, как мне попасть на эту страницу, на которую я отправляю запрос?

Comment: @Сергей Тебе первый комментарий от Алексея говорит об этом. Да и ты в следующем комментарии написал событие после которого должен переходить переход. Правильно мыслишь ) Делаешь на `onready` твоего запроса, и если результат верный (нужный тебе) переходишь на страницу - `location.href = 'someUrl'`.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев я так пытался делать. Получается, что я передаю данные на страницу, они обрабатываются, а когда делаю переход, то страница уже выдает ошибку, так как входящих данных у нее уже нет

Comment: @Сергей дак они и не должны быть, ты отправил данные, они записались в бд, а при обращении к бд, сервер возвращает тебе нужные данные и генерирует таблицу. Все делай через сервер. Отправил данные на сервер => они обработались (записались в бд) => перешел на стриницу => данные запросились => страница сгенерировалась

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Спасибо, я про базу данных и не подумал совсем. У меня не было намерения хранить эти данные, они только для разового применения. Вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правила работы веб-сайтов очень просты.

Если переданная на страницу информация **не сохраняется**, а служит только для построения информациитна этой самой странице, то должен использоваться метод GET.  В этом случае никаких джейсонов, а обычный квери стринг через амперсанд.

Если переданная на страницу информация сохраняется в базе, то сначала записываем, получаем уникальный идентификатор страницы, которая нам покажет сохраненную информацию, и редиректимся на нее.

Comment: спасибо, get для меня не подходит, так как строка json может быть очень большая